# Trouble setting up wireless fedora 17

Tags: fedora, wifi

My distro is fedora 17 Gnome -64, and the wireless adapter is Edimax EW-7612UAn V2. I never used wireless on this computer and it is not so long ago I installed this op system. I installed wireless on another computer with fedora 17 few years ago, but I don't remember how to set it up.

There is no wireless showing up anywhere, and I couldn't set it up with network connection because it didn't see the adapter, I think.

This is what I've done:

I've built the wpa_supplicant, had one error, but fixed it. The driver won't build I think, the only directions where to build and make wpa_supplicant, but now I found that there is a driver folder to with a makefile, can't build that one, says that a folder is missing. This is from the file on their website to build. But there is no wireless. I've done everything in the readme file from the vendor. But no wireless showing up?

```
sudo lshw -c network -sanitize
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82573E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: p1p1
   version: 03
   serial: [REMOVED]
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.2.14-k duplex=full firmware=1.0-7 ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:42 memory:d0080000-d009ffff memory:d0000000-d007ffff ioport:4000(size=32)
```

After I took the extension cord "off" the adapter, the system could see it:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@3:1
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: [REMOVED]
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64 firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

But it says that the hardware is disabled? In the network manager

Comment: Do you have a newer version of Fedora? F17 is past its end of life. If you can't upgrade LMK and I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: Whats LMK? I like fedora 17 best. I have it on two computers. Had something to do with gnome/user interface of F18.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought I'd ask. Sorry short for "Let Me Know".

Comment: Emphasizing what slm said: Since F17 is past its end-of-life, it no longer receives any sort of updates, including security updates.  So if for example someone was to discover a [critical SSL vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-0092), you're not going to get fixes.  F20 is the current release, and F21 is coming Real Soon Now.

Comment: Ok I'll soon setup some more computers, I'll probably update fedora then.

Comment: Maybe I should change this question to F20 or F21, when I do, so its more relevant.

Comment: @slm I've used your answer, the output is updated to my question.

Comment: Based on that output your hardware isn't even being detected by the OS. Notice that's just the Ethernet device, and not the Wireless as in my example. On the off chance that there is some difference with the `lshw` tool itself, can you run it like this and manually confirm that there is no mention of "wireless" in the output? `sudo lshw | less`, then scroll through the output.

Comment: @slm It's confirmed, there is no mention of the wireless

Comment: Do you happen to have dmidecode installed? That will query the BIOS to find out additional info about your hardware. Try that.

Comment: @slm The same, no mention of wireless

Comment: Is there a switch by chance on the laptop that will turn off the antenna for the WiFi? I have one on my Thinkpad T410, most laptops have them. Here's a pic: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-KmM8G-kKqzA/TYqxLyTS5OI/AAAAAAAADN0/7te05atqMEc/s1600/Screen+shot+2011-03-23+at+9.39.36+PM.png

Comment: @slm Sorry, both my fedora computers are stationary. (Desktops)

Comment: Its possible that the old kernel in Fedora 17 doesn't support that hardware.  You could try a LiveCD of Fedora 20 to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks.......... Hope there is someone with solution or know what to do, it's going to be a while before I update my computers(F20/F21)

Comment: @somethingSomething - the suggestion of using a LiveCD doesn't require a install, just booting the hardware using the LiveCD and checking to see if the WiFi works. You do not have to install anything to try this out, just burning the ISO to a DVD and rebooting. You could try this in ~15 min. and know if your issue lies with F17.

Comment: @somethingSomething - without knowing more details about your WiFi hardware (such as a model #) there is nothing else anyone will be able to do for you to help debug this further. It's your issue so you're the one having to deal w/ it but we need more information. I'd like to help but w/o more info I'm at a impass.

Comment: @slm Please see my updated question.

Comment: @somethingSomething - what extension chord did you remove? I'm not following.

Comment: @slm The adapter is just an antenna with an usb, and in it came with an extension so the usb chord is longer. You see, there where two pieces in the package, antenna with usb, and an usb to go between computer and antenna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in this similar Q&A titled: [No wired ethernet connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118850/no-wired-ethernet-connection/118879#118879), you want to start at the bottom of the stack when debugging networking issues. Use the following command to confirm that your WiFi NIC has a driver associated with it.

```
$ sudo lshw -c network -sanitize
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: [REMOVED]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.12.11-201.fc19.x86_64 firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:44 memory:f2400000-f2401fff
```

Pay special attention to the `configuration:` line, looking for the portion that shows `driver=...`.

Comment: sudo lshw -c network -sanitize
sudo: lshw: command not found
sudo lshw -c network -sanitize
sudo: lshw: command not found
 sudo lshw -c network -sanitize  *-network
sudo: lshw: command not found

Comment: I tried this command

Comment: @somethingSomething - you may have to install `lshw`. `sudo yum install lshw`.